# How to verify X.509 certificate was signed by another certificate?

Tags: ios, swift, security, x509

**The story:** I call a request where I am getting a JWS token which I parse with the [JOSESwift](https://github.com/airsidemobile/JOSESwift) library. In the response I have a `x5u` parameter, which is a URL pointing to a certificate, which was used to sign the payload. I download the certificate and using JOSESwift I verify that. With some simplification I am doing the following:

```
let serverCert = // Getting the downloaded certificate as a SecCertificate object
var publicKey: SecKey!
publicKey = SecCertificateCopyKey(serverCert)

let rsaVerifier = RSAVerifier(algorithm: .ES256, publicKey: publicKey)

if let headerVerifier = Verifier(verifyingAlgorithm: .RS256, publicKey: rsaVerifier.publicKey) {
    do {
        _ = try jws.validate(using: headerVerifier)
        print("Verifying success")
    } catch {
        print("Verifying failed with error:", error)
    }
}
```

**Question1**: This is working nice so far. Now I want to verify that the downloaded certificate was indeed signed by a specific certificate I store locally in my application. And that's where I am stuck, that I am unable to find out how it could be done.

**Question2:** A requirement for the functionality is that the locally stored certificate can be self-signed, but also it can be some other certificate from a chain. So basically I should trust the locally stored certificate regardless it is self-signed or not. Is it doable, or when verifying we should always know about the root certificate ?

```
[rootCert] <--signed by-- [localCert] <--signed by-- [receivedCert] // We have only the local and receivedCert
```

**My thoughts/ What I tried:** My first thought was to use a `SecTrust` object, with setting the locally stored certificate as the trust anchor, and use the `SecTrustEvaluateWithError(_:_:)` to check if it's is a correct chain(what I conclude eventually will check also if the received certificate was signed by the one I store locally). I have seen working this in SSLPinning implementations, but somehow it is returning me `false`, even though I double checked that the certificates are correct. Here is what I am doing:

```
let serverCert = // Getting my server cert as a SecCertificate object
let localCert = // Getting my server cert as a SecCertificate object
let policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()
var optionalTrust: SecTrust?
let status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates([serverCert] as AnyObject,
                                            policy,
                                            &optionalTrust)
guard status == errSecSuccess else { return }
let trust = optionalTrust! // Safe to force unwrap now
SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, [localCert] as CFArray)
var error: CFError?
print("Veryfing result: ", SecTrustEvaluateWithError(trust, &error))
print(error)
```

Is it a good approach to verify that the received certification was signed by the local one ? If yes than what I am doing wrong that I am getting `false` ? If the approach is bad, what else can I try here ?

I found a similar question, but it is in Java(but maybe can give a hint what I am trying to accomplish): [Verify x509 signature Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58135614/7119329). However it also mentions the root certificate, so it again rises me the **Question2** if it's doable without the root/self-signed certificate.

**Update**

As suggested in the comments, I am printing the error I am getting from `SecTrustEvaluateWithError`:

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-25318 "“AuthInfoKey:18”
> certificate is not trusted"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=“AuthInfoKey:18” certificate is not
> trusted, NSUnderlyingError=0x280efb9c0 {Error
> Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-25318 "Certificate 0
> “AuthInfoKey:18” has errors: Unable to build chain to root (possible
> missing intermediate);" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Certificate 0
> “AuthInfoKey:18” has errors: Unable to build chain to root (possible
> missing intermediate);}}}

The issues seems reasonable as I do not have access to the root certificate as mentioned above, I want to verify an intermediate certificate.

So again my question is: it possible to check the serverCert(an intermediate certificate) was signed by my local certificate(an other intermediate certificate) with `SecTrustEvaluateWithError` ? For me it seems it is working only if one has also the root certificate.

Comment: "what I am doing wrong that I am getting false?" As always, pass an error object to `SecTrustEvaluateWithError ` in order to obtain the error. Print the error which contains the most sever error of the trust evaluation: `var err: CFError?; SecTrustEvaluateWithError(trust, &err)`.  The answer of whether you _should_ or _need to_ or completely omit trust evaluation of your _public key_ obtained from some endpoint is likely a "it depends" kinda answer. You would do this if you need the source of your JWS to be _authenticated_.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I updated my question including the error I am getting. The thing is I want to make the validation somehow, but can't figure out the way how it could be done.

Comment: The last certificate in the chain must be an anchor certificate or a certificate that the "user" has explicitly chosen to trust or distrust. You can use a self signed cert: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/trust/configuring_a_trust   (if you have setup all certs correctly your code should work IMHO)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I understand. Meaning that can't use `SecTrustEvaluateWithError` for evaluating without a root certificate. But is there any other way to verify if certificate was signed by an other without a root cert on iOS ?

Comment: Well, trying to walk on the standard path, no. (you may analyse the error and then decide based on this, but I never recommend this). This is the chain of trust: the last cert must be trusted. Usually, these are preinstalled certificates which are bundled with the OS. You can set your own with `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates ` - if you trust it. If you just want to omit to trust the root cert, you may also very well not evaluate the trust at all.

Comment: But another question: suppose you secure your TLS connection (or trust it as it is), then whatever you get from that endpoint can be trusted. So, if you receive a JWT, it originates from a trusted source. If you also receive the public key from a trusted source, IMHO it would be sufficient to verify the JWT with this key.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. However because of some business decisions, I need to introduce an other layer of verification, which is exactly this comparing the two certificates.

Comment: You may use _certificate pinning_ to verify the cert - BUT you should do your own research first! This is not without its own risks and your own implementation may introduce more risks than security. As a start: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29988/what-is-certificate-pinning

Comment: I think SSLPinning is a bit different thing from what I want to achieve here. I just want to simply verify if one certificate was signed by another certificate, that's it. Also I have searched for some libraries on the internet, but mostly they use the `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates` method, which again requires a root certificate. But I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Well, why is then using a copy of your CA's root certificate (your `localCert` value) not an option? (this is then your "root", you omit any other, and just only trust `localCert`).

Comment: Just to clear up a potential misconception: if you call `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates` with a set of certs, ONLY the specified cert(s) will be considered for being the anchor certs. This is what you did in your example code, and given the certs have been created correctly, the evaluation with policy X.509 should have worked. X.509 does not check the host name, though - which can be a security issue.

Comment: Yes, that I understand. But again the problem is with the root cert that according some business spec I will not have access to the root cert every time, so I have to work with any kind of cert here. So `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates` is a nice option if I would have that root cert, but unfortunately I can't trust that I will have it. After searching a bit, an other solution come to my mind: If it would be possible to compare the first(local) certificate `issuer` to the received(server) cert `subject` property, as they have to mach if the server cert was signed by the local cert.